# How to cut off and insulate live 3-phase power?

Tags: electrical

I need to disconnect my 3-phase cables from the power pole to my house. I'm building directly under it and though the contractors say they are okay with it, I would prefer to disconnect for a week or two to be 100% safe.

There is at least one spot where the cable has perished a bit and I can see copper showing through.

This is my plan:

- Wear rubber gloves, rubber shoes; make sure power can't go to ground through me and use a 1000V cable shear.
- Tie the cable on both sides of the cut so that the live end doesn't drop away.
- Cut the cable.
- Run a 6 inch tube of plastic pipe over the live end, and bend it over before taping it closed with plastic electrical tape.
- Coil and hang up the loose end safely away from the building.
- Repeat this process with all 4 cables, keeping them separate.

I am located in South Africa.

Comment: Since you have cable degradation I think the power company would react nearly instantly to a report about it.

Comment: I've cut my own cables before, and lived (obviously) - you'll be fine. But I'm not going to post this as an answer because I don't want the downvotes from all the naysayers and overly-cautious. When you cut it, cut **1 copper wire at a time**. Otherwise, your cutting tool will touch multiple copper wires at once and current will flow through your cutting tool. This won't electrically affect you, but may blow fuses somewhere and cause heat damage to the insulation. Also, wrap the handles of your cutting tool in some cloth to put space (air is an excellent insulator) between you and voltage.

Comment: So I've had a bit of amusement answering questions like these, but it looks like the answers have it covered.  The one addendum I would give is my standard disclaimer for high voltage power: **If you have to ask StackExchange for advice regarding high voltage power, you shouldn't be messing with it.**  Electricity is one of those things where you either already know the answer, or ask someone you trust.  You only get one heart, and it's silly to entrust it to random people on the internet, no matter how much good advice StackExchange may provide on average!

Comment: @Bohemian: "may cause heat damage to the insulation" is a bit of an understatement with mostly unlimited 20kA going through the plasma of what's left of the bolt cutters.

Comment: @insta where I come from, 3-phase is 440V. I assumed this with my comment, in which case "plasma" is an *over* statement.

Comment: So... how, exactly do you plan to *reconnect* these cables?  Shearing live cable is insanity - that's just not the right way to do it.  You go back to the disconnect and switch the power off.  If you need the cables changed, you remove them at the disconnected lugs once the power is off.

Comment: Please do an google image search on the term "electrical injuries". Maintenance on non-secured lines is something even full fledged electricians have the utmost respect. And no, if you do not know how to handle this then even some fancy protection systems like insulated shears, rubber gloves/foil etc. won't protect you

Comment: Also remember to earth non live part of cut cable to discharge any static charge for safety reasons.

Comment: @CortAmmon: could perhaps even make a case that a question like this is too open-ended with too broad a scope for the site. The full details of things that can go fatally wrong, and the list of alternatives to slicing a live supply and how to choose between them, is too long to fit in a reasonable answer. Hence, as you say, even if you completely trust the person giving the answer, an answer on this site can't train you to work up a power pole. Likewise, don't ask on medicine how to set a broken bone: even with an accurate answer you'll mess it up, which is why nurses train for that stuff...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel OP says in a comment elsewhere that they are located in South Africa. I would absolutely believe the story about power company taking 6 months in ZA. I've also seen them do some of the things that would get a workplace shut down in some countries as just a matter of course.

Comment: Please keep us updated with what you do and how it goes  - this is fascinating.

Comment: @dirkpiet its now over three years later.  What happened?

Comment: @dirkpiet  "Last seen more than 4 years ago"  I'm concerned.  Did you attempt to follow your initial plan ?

Comment: @criggie Thanks for your concern I updated the post, kind regards Dirk

Comment: Happy to hear you survived and more so that you called the power company to do it properly. Just because the guy said "that's how we always do it" doesn't mean that he wasn't _trained_ to do it that way and knows how to do it properly and safely. Despite the fact that he borrowed your "aluminum" ladder (do the quotes mean that it's not really AL, or that you're trying to emphasize that it is?) doesn't mean that all the rest of his equipment wasn't specifically designed to keep him safe while doing this job.

Comment: Of course, you can die of electrocution from a 15A/120V circuit and dying by electrocution from a 240V (or whatever) 200A circuit won't make you any more dead...

Comment: Answers/resolutions go in the answer box.

Comment: That they do ([IMHO](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/should-this-is-what-i-did-be-updates-to-the-question-or-stand-alone-answers)), @nobody, however removing them without making an answer out of it (something the OP or a mod can do), leaves a lot of confusion about the most recent set of comments. Please roll back your edits until the change is made, or follow TylerH's suggestion in his answer to the meta post.

Comment: @FreeMan The big difference is that in *almost all cases*, planned work on 120V or 240V circuits within a home (or even outside, but after the main panel) can be done 100% safely by anyone, simply by turning off the breaker first. Which in fact is why almost nobody (hopefully!) replaces a receptacle, switch, etc. with the wires hot - just no reason to do so. But that's not an option for this situation.

Answer (score 63):

Call the utility, ask for a disconnect.

Or call the mortuary and pick out a casket.

This is not a job for amateurs. Nor for gloves not rated and tested for the voltage. But that's just one tiny piece, so don't think solving the gloves is making you qualified to do the work.

Comment: Thanks ecnerwal.  What can happen that makes it so dangerous? Where I live the utility is not an option unless I wait 6 months

Comment: @dirkpiet -- ***6 MONTHS?!??!?!??!!?*** That is utterly outrageous!  I hope they'd disconnect you faster if you stopped paying your bill...

Comment: @dirkpiet You may not have a choice - the utility may require that they do the work as part of your terms of our service with them.

Comment: How did you plan to reconnect the wires after cutting them?  It sounds like if you survive the cutting part, you'll have to wait 6 months anyway for the utility company to come and install new wires from the pole to the house.

Comment: You don't own those wires.  They're not yours to touch.  In fact, disconnecting a meter might bring the DEA around to see whether you have diverted the power for nefarious purposes.

Comment: @SDsolar I wasn't aware that US government agencies had any authority in South Africa, but I have been surprised before...

Comment: DEA is everywhere, among other agencies.  But my focus is on southern Cal.

Comment: @user being a little cheeky, not having authority somewhere doesn't always stop the US...

Answer (score 29):

The cables feeding your house are owned by the power company.

They own everything from the power pole to the main breaker, which includes the meter.

So they will need to be the ones to do the work you describe.

It is a legal issue of ownership, not just of safety.

Before attempting anything like this you should call them and ask what the procedure is for a temporary disconnect.

If you report to them that there is degradation of the cables and exposed wiring, it wouldn't be surprising if they were out there the same day (or night) to have a look.

They might actually do the work at the pole instead of at the house.  But let them decide, since it belongs to them.

If you were to attempt it yourself and had any sort of accident the only protection for their system would be pole-mounted breakers.  A direct short could cause instantaneous unintended disassembly of a transformer or blow the pole-mounted breakers which would most likely cause a neighborhood-wide blackout.

It is unlikely that your insurance would cover a willful act on your part which could cause ramifications to grandma who lives up the street surviving on life-saving medical devices.

Comment: Per-customer pole fuses are standard here in NZ. Depending on where OP is, they may not take out the whole transformer. I've heard bad things about their reliability, though, so don't rely on them...

Comment: I would be interested to see a citation that everywhere in the world, that the power company owns everything from the power pole to the main breaker.
This is definitely not always the case in Australia (for example).
See: https://www.commerce.wa.gov.au/energysafety/private-power-poles-and-lines-are-your-responsibility

Comment: Here in southern California, PG&E does the work on these kinds of lines.  Definitely not the home owner.  PG&E owns the entire electric grid, all the way to your house.  Here is their brief procedure brochure for temporary disconnects:  https://www.pge.com/includes/docs/pdfs/shared/customerservice/otherrequests/newcontruction/BRSC_Guide_ElectricTempDisconnect.pdf

Comment: @SDsolar *THAT PDF...* photo on page 1...   that's a DIN rail board with Euro colors, and the intended audience for that document will know that.  Somebody's jumping the gun on CalExit!

Comment: It's actually *rapid unintentional/unplanned/unscheduled disassembly*, not instantaneous. Nothing in the real world is instantaneous, though it may very well be rapid. Compare [Who coined the phrase 'Rapid Unscheduled Disassembly'?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10022/415) on [space.se].

Comment: So noted.  I almost added uncontrolled.  Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 14):

First, call up the power company and consult with them.  I gather you have a belief you're holding that says "surely it will take 6 months for them to reply". *Challenge that belief.*

**Make sure to mention the insulation failure on the wires.**

If you can't reach them, give a call to the best electrician you can find and see what they think.   For one thing, maybe they can do it at a sane price.

Since you're saying "house", well, we can preclude New York City with its 208 wye since ConEd would be out there same-day.  That leaves the wild untamed world with its 230-to-ground, 400V wye service.  That stuff's not *too* bad, but still to be respected.  Above that, I'd call a pro.

I for one would never cut a cable, but would slide some shrink-tubing over it.

Comment: Also, OP says that the existing cable has "copper showing through" - **tell the lines company**! They will likely want this disconnected ASAP.

Comment: Upvote.  I believe they would come out in the middle of the night if that's what it takes to respond immediately to a report like this.

Comment: Of course that might not help: they'll come immediately, replace all worn/faulty parts inclulding the exposed cable and anything else they find wrong with it, and chances are your electricity will still be connected.

Comment: @SteveJessop I've never dealt with a power company that would knowingly leave the scene with energized conductors at risk. At that point they might as well just leave some business cards of personal injury lawyers.  Of course if OP's nation is in civil disorder, all bets are off.   Seriously though, OP's "6 month" experience may have arisen from calling for a routine matter right after a wind or ice storm.

Comment: @Harper: I mean that what the questioner wants ("my power disconnected for the duration of the building work") is not the same as what the power company treats as an urgent issue ("fix the damaged cables"). Just because they'll rush out to fix/replace it doesn't mean they'll agree to leave it disconnected afterwards for the customer's convenience, and come back to reconnect it at the time of their choosing. That's a different department. I mean, they might do what you ask, but likely they'll fix it asap.

Comment: I still agree that it's best to just ask the power company for what you want rather than *assuming* they'll refuse on the basis that their customer service generally is horrible :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Good point, they might rush out to fix the damaged/exposed wires, and then ignore calls to reapply power to the building, since that is not an emergency.

Answer (score 4):

Though your question is how and not about people's recommendation what you should do, here's an opinion. *(Too long for a comment so I posted as an answer.)*

First, in anything you build, Safety First, and we can see you try to avoid the life threatening wires whilst you build, **though** the contractors already said it's okay. If they are wrong you are in risk. If they are correct, and you still persist to  cut the wires, you are still in risk. So either way, it's risky.

Focus on your goal to stay safe, and remove yourself from the options. Let the company do it for you, or as the other answers said, hire a professional.

*Better stick with your plan, that is – to stay alive.*

Comment: Thanks guys, I live in South Africa where the rules are the same but the response time is poor. Does anyone know how to cut the cables ? I've got the rubber headband , what else do I need?

Comment: @dirkpiet I believe the rubber headband was a joke and I hope your comment is also a joke...

Comment: @dirkpiet -- yell, kick, and scream until they come out and do your bidding.  6 months for a routine disconnect is utterly unacceptable...

Comment: I had one done the other day for tree service, they came next day and they came back to reconnect just a few hours after i called them back

Answer (score 2):

*Answer posted in the original question by the OP. Snarky comments removed.*

No I didn’t cut it myself but I found out I could do a temporary disconnection and reconnect for $30. “I wasn’t aware that it was even possible” so I filled in the forms and a few days later 2 good natured guys with gloves and a wire cutter showed up at my house. They did it exactly how I had described it, but used “plastic insulation tape”. They even borrowed my “aluminium” ladder and cut all 4 wires casually.

“We always do it this way” How long have you been at the city Electrical dept? I asked “32 years” he replied, “call us when you want us to reconnect".

I totally could have done it. But it would have cost much more for the cutters and gloves.

Comment: In addition to training, another key is that they sent **two** guys. With a second person to hold tools, steady the ladder, etc., the person doing the actual cutting/etc. can concentrate on the task at hand.